# AngularJS Call function from another file

Tags: angularjs

When I trying call function from another file I get error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentUserFullName' of undefined

in app.js:

```
    'use strict';

    var testApp = {};

    var App = angular.module('testApp', ['testApp.filters', 'testApp.services', 'testApp.directives',
            'ngRoute']);

    App.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function ($location, $rootScope) {

        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute, AuthUtils) {
           if(!$rootScope.userFullName){
                var userFullName = AuthUtils.getCurrentUserFullName();
                if(userFullName) {
                    $rootScope.userFullName = userFullName;
                    $rootScope.authenticate = true;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.authenticate = false;
                    $rootScope.userFullName = "";
                }
            }
        });

    }]);
```

AuthUtils.js

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('testApp')
        .factory('AuthUtils', function AuthUtils($rootScope, $http) {
            return {
                getCurrentUserFullName: function () {
                    $http.get('auth/userFullName').success(function (user) {
                        return user;
                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                        return "error";
                        console.error(status, data);
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Why doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to inject `AuthUtils` inside `run` block. Inject it so factory instance would be available in run block

```
App.run(['$location', '$rootScope', 'AuthUtils', //<== injected AuthUtils here
    function ($location, $rootScope, AuthUtils) { //<== and here
```

Additonally you need to remove `AuthUtils` parameter from `$routeChangeSuccess` function, which was killing existence of injected `AuthUtils` in run block.

Change to

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute) //<--removed AuthUtils
```

From

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute, AuthUtils)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now I've an error "Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthUtilsProvider%20%3C-%20AuthUtils"

Comment: Thank you, I did as above and I changed order import js files and works!

Comment: @Pablo glad to know that.. do upvote & accept answer..if it does helped you.. Thanks :-)